# Get File Path of Selected File

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript which opens an excel file and takes data from it. The path to the excel file is hard coded so the file must be named the same and must be in the same location.

```
Set objWorkbook = objWbs.Open("C:\Users\name\Desktop\form.xls")
```

I want to make it so that when the script is run it shows an explorer where the used can then choose the file that they want to use and it would take the path of that file and use that path instead of the hard coded one.

I searched before asking the question but could not find a solution. Is this possible? or a similar solution and how would I go about doing it?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not well-versed in VBScript, but I would say that you could put in a text box and let the user type in a well-formed path. You could always do a check to see if it's got any bad characters or if the file doesn't exist and give them a message if there's a problem. Coding a full browse functionality seems like it would be a lot harder, but I've never tried and am not too familiar with VBScript, so I'm not positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work for all file types, but curiously .xls is one of the supported files.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

On Error Resume Next
Set objFile=objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a XLS file:", &h4001&, "c:\") 

If Not objFile is Nothing Then

    WScript.Echo objFile.Title
    WScript.Echo objFile.self.Path

End If
```